# pathogen installation failed?

Tags: macos, vim, pathogen

I have .vim folder in my home folder
and pathogen.vim in .vim/autoload/
I followed the guide for pathogen on vim.org by put

```
"call pathogen#infect()"
```

into my vimrc

when I run vim

I got "E117: Unknown function: pathogen#infect"
my vimrc

```
runtime autoload/pathogen.vim
call pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags()
set hlsearch
set incsearch
set ignorecase
set autoindent
set smartindent
syntax on
set number
set ruler
set showmatch
```

So frustrated with configuring vim

my vim version is:VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3

Comment: You should remove the two `"`

Comment: no i don't have " " in my vimrc, I tried u previous reply, I got more error:

Comment: Error detected while processing /usr/share/vim/vimrc:
line    4:
E117: Unknown function: pathogen#infect
line    5:
E117: Unknown function: pathogen#helptags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `pathogen.vim` is in `~/.vim/autoload`, trying adding "call pathogen#infect()" and "call pathogen#helptags()" to `~/.vimrc` instead of `/usr/share/vim/vimrc`. It appears that you are trying to call functions defined in `pathogen.vim` from the system `vimrc` file before it can be loaded from your personal `vim` directory.

Comment: Hi! While following your advice above does remove the error for me, my plugins still don't work. I don't have jade highlighting for instance and I can use the surrounds plugin.